# Historical use of k in proof by induction

Tags: induction, math-history

Does anybody know the history of why the symbol *k* is used in proof by induction?

As an example, in physics the symbol *p* is used for momentum because Newton called it *impetus*, and the letters *i* and *m* were already taken for index and mass, respectively, and *p* was next.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but where I live (Belgium), $n$ is used about equally often in induction proofs

Comment: It is I think just a teaching device, to avoid confusion with the universally quantified $n$.